# BKE_bpath_absolute_convert: basedir='', this is a bug

Tags: python

I am getting this error in the terminal after running my script(2.79b). What am I supposed to do?

This is basically my script

```
import bpy
import os 
import glob 
import time
import tempfile

fname = bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)

 fname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

 tempFolder=tempfile.gettempdir()

 finalpath=os.path.join(tempfolder,fname)

 bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=finalpath, copy=True)
```

thanks

Comment: You're supposed to give us some information we can use to solve your problem. What script are you running? Have you tried minimising your script to the absolute minimum number of lines of code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: You're not importing any Python modules?

Comment: Sorry did not  think it wsa relevant. I added the imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning to `fname` but then you're using `filename` in the next line. Same for `tempFolder` and `tempfolder`. This runs without error:

```
import bpy
import os 
import tempfile

filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)
fname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
tempfolder = tempfile.gettempdir()
finalpath = os.path.join(tempfolder, fname)
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=finalpath, copy=True)
```